# Pass +RTS options to program run with stack exec

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How do I pass `+RTS` options to a program run with `stack exec`?

I've added `-rtsopts` to `ghc-options` in my cabal file, and built a program with `stack build`. If I run the program manually both normal and `+RTS` command line arguments work:

```
>.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\iterate-strict-exe\iterate-strict-exe.exe 25 +RTS -s
OK
   3,758,156,184 bytes allocated in the heap
         297,976 bytes copied during GC
         ...
```

But if I run it with `stack exec` only the normal options reach the program

```
>stack exec iterate-strict-exe -- 25 +RTS -s
OK
```

#### Other things that don't work

If I juggle the order of the arguments around as suggested by @epsilonhalbe I get the same result.

```
>stack exec -- iterate-strict-exe 25 +RTS -s
OK
```

---

There doesn't seem to be the suggested `--rts-options` option to pass to `stack exec`.

```
>stack exec --rts-options "-s" -- iterate-strict-exe 25
Invalid option `--rts-options'

Usage: stack exec CMD [-- ARGS (e.g. stack ghc -- X.hs -o x)] ([--plain] |
                  [--[no-]ghc-package-path] [--[no-]stack-exe] [--package ARG])
                  [--help]
  Execute a command
```

I'm using `stack` version `1.1.2`

```
>stack --version
Version 1.1.2, Git revision c6dac65e3174dea79df54ce6d56f3e98bc060ecc (3647 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.14.0
```

---

The same after a `stack upgrade` to `1.4.0`.

---

Passing the entire command as a string (another suggestion) results in a command with that name not being found

```
>stack exec -- "iterate-strict-exe 25 +RTS -s"
Executable named iterate-strict-exe 25 +RTS -s not found on path: ...
```

Comment: i think it is the other way 'round `stack exec -- iterate-strict-exe 25 +RTS -s`

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Nope, that didn't do it.

Comment: I just saw there is a flag `--rts-options` you might need to try `--rts-options "+RTS -s"` and `--rts-options "-s"`

Comment: also - though I am not a 100% sure you can pass the whole thing as a string to stack and it executes it `stack exec -- "iterate-strict-exe 20 +RTS -s"` is another thing I'd try.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Neither of those work either.

Comment: I don't know whether it is relevant but your stack version is outdated

Comment: Just tested on 1.1.2, `stack exec iterate-strict-exe -- 25 +RTS -s` and `stack exec -- iterate-strict-exe 25 +RTS -s` both work, so something else is wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are on Windows and encountering GHC bug [#13287](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13287) (to be fixed in 8.2). See also stack issues [2022](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2022) and [2640](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2640). Apparently a workaround is to add `--RTS` before `--`, like

```
stack exec iterate-strict-exe --RTS -- 25 +RTS -s
```